# Execute xp_cmdshell command as specific user

Tags: sql-server, windows, t-sql, shell

I would like to run **xp_cmdshell** (TSQL procedure) in order to mount a network drive and then access remotes mdb files.

I am administrator on the MS SQL server and I have allowed **xp_cmdshell** execution accordingly.

However, there is still a problem:

- When I call xp_cmdshell, the user executing the command is the SQL *SysAdmin*, i.e. the account who run SQL Server process.
- I wish **xp_cmdshell** executes as the account with which I'm connected to SQL server, i.e *Administrator*

Both of theses account are in administrator group, SQLAdmin group, and are granted to CONTROL SERVER. Both users belong to the same domain. All of this is run on the same machine.

Because of this conflict, I cannot use a network drive because it is mounted for *SysAdmin* and not for *Administrator*
I tried to use **sp_ xp_ cmdshell_ proxy_ account** to specify the account with which I want to run **xp_cmdshell**, but *SysAdmin* is still the used account.

Therefore, this code :
    `select user_name(), suser_name;`
    `exec xp_cmdshell 'echo %username%';`

displays :
    `Administrator Administrator`
    `SysAdmin`

Does anybody knows how to impersonate well the **xp_cmdshell** command ? Is there something to (re)configure?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The proxy account is only used when non-sysadmin users execute xp_cmdshell

Comment: Then how can I force a specific sysadmin user ?

Comment: Just to clarify - you've used sp_xp_cmd_shell_proxy_account to set the account you want to use, and then executed the command using xp_cmdshell, and the account used is still the service account? I just want to make sure I understand your steps.

Answer (score 10):

Because you're connecting to SQL as a login in the sysadmin group, `xp_cmdshell` runs as the service account.

If you connect as a low-privilege login, then it will use the `xp_cmdshell_proxy_account` instead. So try doing `EXECUTE AS LOGIN='lowprivaccount'` first, to see if that helps.

Of course, what you're actually asking is not the expected use. Expected use is that the high-privilege accounts can allow `xp_cmdshell` to use the Service Account, whereas everyone else has to put up with the lower privilege proxy account.

Comment: So... do you really need to be running this using a security context in the sysadmin server role? Ideally you should only be using the sysadmin role when you need to do sysadmin things.

Answer (score 3):

I actually have had to use this method in the past for similar things on network shares, try this...

> -- map your drive and make it persistent.
>
> xp_cmdshell"net use t: \\<server>\<share> <password> /user:<username> /persistent:yes"
>
> -- t-sql code making use of the t drive
>
> -- delete the drive mapping xp_cmdshell"net use t: /delete"

you can actually set up a job that executes when sql service starts and make it map this drive so you will always have access to the share as long as sql is running.  All you would need to do is setup a sproc that maps the drive and have it do the initial mapping of the drive and make use of sp_procoption (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181720.aspx)

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would map a drive rather than just reference a UNC path directly?

Comment: @Pondlife Sometimes, when you are using alternate credentials to connect to a UNC (Not on your domain), it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try PsExec? Download the file at this URL and copy it in a folder member of the %Path% environment variable.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'psexec -u Administrator -p password net use ...'
```

Comment: This may be a solution, but It implies writing the password in plain text, which is tricky.

I'm looking for a pure TSQL way...

Comment: Hi thanks for ur update, but when i tried same  with below command    "exec xp_cmdshell 'C:\Adhoc\PSTools\psexec -u domain\id -p password dir \\sharelocation'"   This is running forever without any result, please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You could try "net use" with a username and password inside xp_cmdshell. This establishes the credentials for the connection to the UNC.

However, I'm not sure how long this would persist. If it persists indefinitely (eg until server restart), you could have a start-up stored procedure that does "net use" and ensures it's available for use later.

A subsequent xp_cmdshell (to access the MDB files) would not require the authentication because the credentials are already established within the OS.

Comment: I'm almost ashamed to admit it, but this works. It's terrible from a security point of view, but I have done it out of desperation. BUT - are you opening MDB files directly from a network disk? That would keep me up nights. What I was doing was home-grown log shipping in an environment with no domain (i.e. just file copy operations)

Answer (score 0):

I found this page helped fill in the gaps in the process of actually adding the domain account and linking it.

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2007/08/23/xp-cmdshell-and-permissions.aspx

Answer (score -1):

After restart server must execute command plase solution save command...

```
Use Master GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 RECONFIGURE WITH 
OVERRIDE GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1 RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE GO

exec xp_cmdshell 'net use \ip\xxx pass /user:xxx /persistent:no'

Use Master GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 RECONFIGURE WITH 
OVERRIDE GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0 RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
```

Answer (score -2):

You must create a stored procedure to which you will place your xp_cmdshell script in it.

A stored procedure runs using the administrator account, therefore your xp_cmdshell will successfully run when you execute the stored procedure

```
create procedure RunShellIndirectly

as

declare @tawandachinaka as varchar(50)

set @tawandachinaka='DIR "c:\scrap measurement\"*.csv /B' 

EXEC xp_cmdshell @tawandachinaka
```

Comment: "A stored procedure runs using the administrator account": this is [not correct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354(v=sql.100).aspx).

Comment: A stored procedure runs (as far as the OS is concerned) using the currently assigned SQL service account and the SP can only run if the SQL permissions (set in security) allow it.