# Issues while using xp_cmdshell to run from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a SQL Server Agent Job, using a proxy account `A` and the agent job executes a stored procedure, which uses the `xp_cmdshell` to run an exe.

SQL Server Agent and SQL Server are running under account `B`.

I have created proxy credentials for account `A` and it has access full access to the director which contains the executable.

When I try to execute the job and log which account is running under (using xp_cmdshell 'whoami')  it logs account `B`.

Is there someway I can run this under account `A`?

Can someone please help?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092163/execute-xp-cmdshell-command-as-specific-user).  It has to do with what account the XP_CmdShell command is running under.  (Please note that xp_cmdshell can be exploited as [a security vulnerability](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2722/xp-cmdshell-should-it-ever-be-used) and you should be careful when allowing it on your server.)