# Very Confused About SQL Server/SSMS Job Network Access/Accounts

Tags: sql-server

Okay all, the subject is a pretty poor one, but I'm not sure how else to put it. I have Server 2012 with a bunch of jobs, all owned by `sa`. They all worked fine ever since I began working here in January 2016, but we recently made *major* changes to our servers. Currently, we have a few servers off the domain, and set up together as a workgroup. They're clones of what we were running before the shakeup, so include all the data/logins. The main difference is that they can't talk to our Active Directory anymore.

Back to SQL Server. Some of the jobs on the server have to read from and write to an FTP folder on one of the servers which is in the same workgroup. That is, both the 2012 server and the FTP server are on the same workgroup, so *should* talk to each other with no problem. However, some of the jobs keep failing because of logon errors when trying to connect to the FTP server. I'm not using FTP, but rather network locations, like `\\1.2.3.4\ftp\folder\file.txt` in my job code. This worked perfectly until the servers moved. Skipping the long and confusing reasons why, suffice it to say that this server won't be back in contact with Active Directory for some time. Indeed, letting it be so can't happen until we can shut down its on-domain counterpart. However, we can't do that until I get this working sans domain contact. Again, long story behind that catch-22.

My questions after dealing with all this are:

- If the job in question is owned by `sa`, why do the logs show logon attempts by `nt access\network` authority?
- How/where can I change the username/password the 2012 server is using to talk to the FTP server?
- Is there a way I could access the FTP server, given the workgroup setup in place, that's easier than what I'm trying to do now? Sharing settings on the FTP folder, for instance?

Thanks for any explanations anyone can offer. I'm thoroughly confused about permissions, accounts, credentials, and remote access and have no idea where to turn, having googled all of this exhaustively.

Comment: How do you access FTP if you're not using SSIS? With `xp_cmdshell`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Most of the jobs in question find data from one or more databases, compile it into a temporary table, then use bcp to output it into files which are saved via cmdshell to \\someIP\ftp\someFolder\info.txt. That's how it was set up when I started working here, so that's what I've kept doing. I've never dealt with MSSQL or jobs running it before.

Comment: When I say FTP, I mean an FTP server that our customers are meant to access. We put the data on there for them to use via local network access. We don't use FTP directly, though if there's a way to do that, perhaps we should consider that in place of the current, direct-over-network method.

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/q/1092163/11683 helpful then?

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't get anything in that post to work. Running cmdshell as a specific user gave me an error, and trying to map the server as a drive--which I've done in Windows with no problem--works at first before SSMS complains that the path was not found.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with servers that were not domain joined, but I have had similar issues when using SSIS accross sub-domains (see original answer below for more detail). I would look at the setup of sql server and see what service accounts were used for the sql database service and the sql agent service (check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx). ALso, make sure that the server accounts have permissions to the file system locations (you likely already did that, but just in case).

Original Answer for SSIS Situations ( I misunderstood that the asker wasn't using SSIS):
You might need to set up a proxy to control what account is used. There is a section on proxies in this article that you might find helpful. I suggest reading the entire article, it might shed some light.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/setting-up-your-sql-server-agent-correctly/

Comment: Thanks. From that article, and others I've since looked up regarding proxy accounts, it looks like proxies are for SSIS packages? The jobs I have are nearly all T-SQL only, and I can't find a way of specifying a credential to be used when running those.

Comment: After more reading, proxies are definitely for SSIS only. Jobs, it seems, are given credentials by their owner. This leads me back to my original question: how do I set the credentials a job owner has, which would then be used to talk to a workgroup computer during the job execution?

Comment: Sorry, I made an assumption that you were using SSIS since you were talking about an  FTP location.